# Static template data members storage

Tags: c++, templates, static-members

First I'll write example to properly address the question.

First of all, I'll declare template to be used to create singleton object (not auto-created):
**singleton_base.h**

```
template <class Derived>
class SingletonBase
{
  public:
    static Derived* instance() { assert(s_instance); return dynamic_cast<Derived*>(s_instance); }
  protected:
    SingletonBase() { assert(s_instance==0); s_instance=this; }
    virtual ~SingletonBase() { assert(s_instance); s_instance=0; }
  private:
    static SingletonBase* s_instance;
};

template <class Derived>
SingletonBase<Derived>* SingletonBase<Derived>::s_instance = 0;
```

Now we can declare any class that derived from template, and each derived class should have its own s_instance. For example:

**child1.h**

```
class Child1 : public SingletonBase<Child1>
{
  ...
  void doSomething();
  static void staticInvokeOne();
};
```

**child2.h**

```
class Child2 : public SingletonBase<Child2>
{
  ...
  void doSomethingElse();
  static void staticInvokeBoth();
};
```

I also have Child's implementation in **child1.cpp** and **child2.cpp** respectively.

**child1.cpp**

```
void Child1::staticInvokeOne()
{
  instance()->doSomething();
}
```

**child2.cpp**

```
void Child2::staticInvokeBoth()
{
  Child1::instance()->doSomething();
  instance()->doSomethingElse();
}
```

Now I have `Child1` and `Child2` having their own `s_instance` and they will point to the only instance of that class at given moment.

The question is about storage for this static data member `s_instance`. Unlike with regular static data members I have not specified where it should be allocated. I would, of course, like to have `SingletonBase<Child1>::s_instance` and `SingletonBase<Child2>::s_instance` in **child1.o** and **child2.o** respectively, but is that something I can expect or enforce?

The issue gets more complicated if I put `Child1` and `Child2` into two distinct libraries - **lib1** and **lib2**. Inside `Child2::staticInvokeBoth()` there is a call to `Child1::instance()`. As far as I understand, default gcc's behaviour is to generate a copy of `SingletonBase<Child1>::s_instance` in each compilation unit, thus one copy will be emitted in **lib2**.

Will it also generate a copy of `SingletonBase<Child1>::s_instance` in **lib2**? Definitely, one copy of `SingletonBase<Child1>::s_instance` should be in **lib1**. If those two libraries are later used together in one application, can I be sure that there is only one instance of `SingletonBase<Child1>::s_instance` and that both `Child1::staticInvokeOne()` and `Child2::staticInvokeBoth()` are using it?

Is it generally safe to use this approach with statics wrapped in template, or are there any drawbacks?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this is the same as with any other template-based or inline function - the only difference is in this case the variable ends up being marked for placement in a read-write section.

In most compilers, the compiler will instantiate any needed template functions and static member variables in *every compilation unit they are referenced in*. The compiler will also mark these as 'weak symbols'; this means that, at the final link phase, the linker will choose one of the emitted copies arbitrarily to go into the final executable.

Note, however, that the weak symbol consolidation process is usually done at the static linking stage. The dynamic linker will *not* do this for you. As such, you should avoid having mutable (read-write) template static data members in shared libraries. Also avoid address comparisons on read-only template static data members across shared libraries (including RTTI data).

And keep in mind in general with shared libraries that almost any change in template definitions that cross the ABI boundrary will break your ABI - so it's probably best to avoid templates entirely in shared library APIs!

Comment: Hm... Does it also apply to shared libraries? Will those names be resolved at runtime by dynamic linker (assuming linux)? Can it be mislead by DT_SYMBOLIC?

Comment: Shared libraries can be broken, badly, by this stuff. I've been bitten by issues with this stuff before across shared libs; usually the weak symbols are resolved at final link time, and can no longer be merged at dynamic link time. Stick with static libs, or don't use static members in template types at all.

Answer (score 0):

Though I may misunderstand your question, if *storage* in your question
means *definition*, my answer might apply.
As for one definition rule, 3.2 p5 of the standard says:

> There can be more than one definition
>   of ... static data member of a class
>   template ... in a program provided
>   that each definition appears in a
>   different translation unit,

and

> If the definitions of D satisfy all
>   these requirements, then the program
>   shall behave as if there were a single
>   definition of D.

There are some requirements for this rule. In this question's case,
since the variable is
initialized by an integral constant 0, the requirements are satisfied.